# How to rotate a rectangle in Win2D

Tags: animation, uwp, win2d

I'm looking for a way to rotate a rectangular image (or any image for that matter) around its center point using Win2D.

This snippet is from within the OnDraw method for the Win2D canvas:

```
var redBitMap = _images[1];
var yellowBitMap = _images[2];

var rect = new Rect(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y, _width, _height);
_drawingSession.DrawImage(redBitMap, rect);

ICanvasImage image = new Transform2DEffect
{
   Source = yellowBitMap,
   TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)(60 * Math.PI / 180)),
};
var sourceRect = image.GetBounds(_drawingSession);
_drawingSession.DrawImage(image, rect), sourceRect, 1, CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic);
```

This method gives me my image rotated by 60 degrees, but the image ends up being drawn at the wrong coordinates, skewed and smaller than the intended image.

Interestingly enough, if I change the size of the rectangle so that it is square (making the height the same as the width), the image is no longer skewed.

[image: Yellow hex over Red hex]

After giving it more thought, here is what is happening:
[image: Actually happening]

So, the yellow rectangle represents the image I want to rotate (on center) by 60 degrees.  The red rectangle that is anchored to the top left corner is what is happening when I rotate it.  The big blue box is the new rectangle created that is determined by the image.GetBounds statement.

When I try to draw the image back to the original coordinates, you can see from the right hand image that it's causing the image to be both skewed and shrunk because the source rectangle is no longer the same size or shape as the target rectangle.

If my geometry skills were better, I could surely calculate the bounds of the new rectangle and apply them to the correct location back onto the canvas.  But alas, it's been too many years since high-school math for me.  On a one-off calculation, I'm sure I could figure it out - but not when the shape of the source image might change.

Comment: Have you checked win2D sample of Transform3DEffect to rotate an image around its center?

Comment: Maybe it's getting clipped because of Width and Height of CanvasControl? Did you try to make it larger?

Comment: I have looked at the Transform3DEffect samples and none are what I'm looking for.  There is one there, but the image ends up clipping when it try to use the sample code (which rotates at the corner, not in the middle.

Comment: @JetChopper - there is plenty of room for the image on the canvas.  The clipping seems to happen because the new image no longer fits within the bounds of the original rectangle.

Comment: Update post with XAML and code behind

Comment: I'll try to create a repro project.  Due to NDA issues, I cannot provide the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jet, your suggestion helped me find the answer. What I needed to do was not use the ScaleEffect, but that's what gave me the clue I needed. The final draw image needed to take into account the changing size (much the same idea as the ScaleEffect. This left me with the following line of code:

```
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(image, new Rect(topLeft.X + (_width - sourceRect.Width)/2, topLeft.Y + (_height - sourceRect.Height)/2, sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height), sourceRect, 1, CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the clue:

```
        var scaleFactor = rect.Height / rect.Width;

        ICanvasImage image2 = new ScaleEffect
        {
            Source = image,
            Scale = new Vector2((float)scaleFactor, 1)
        };

        args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(image2, rect, sourceRect, 1, CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic);
```

Paste this code instead you last line. Hope you'll get what you want :)

[image]

Scale is happening (looks like skew) when you're trying to draw one rectange into another with different aspect ratios.

Comment: Thank you!  The ScaleEffect fixes the skew portion, but it still leaves the rotated image smaller than the original image.  It's because after the rotation, the source rectangle has become larger than the original rectangle.  Perhaps there is a way to apply a similar scaling based on the change in rectangle size?

Comment: Jet, your suggestion helped me find the answer.  What I needed to do was not use the ScaleEffect, but that's what gave me the clue I needed.  The final draw image needed to take into account the changing size (much the same idea as the ScaleEffect.  This left me with the following line of code: args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(image, new Rect(topLeft.X + (_width - sourceRect.Width)/2, topLeft.Y + (_height - sourceRect.Height)/2, sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height), sourceRect, 1,                                   CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic);

Comment: I could have posted my final line of code as the answer, but it was your clue that brought me to the solution - so I've given you the correct answer.

Comment: @PaulMouchet - thanks for the question (and answer) - please do put your answer as the accepted answer.  Future readers may miss your comment with the *real* answer.